# Dynamic Auto Sharding support for Scala Slick

Tags: scala, slick, sharding, typesafe

This post is related to the issue already raised at [Dynamically changing the database shard that I am connecting too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311838/dynamically-changing-the-database-shard-that-i-am-connecting-too).

Pointers to code that should be changed to implement this feature is given at https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/703

Am a newbie to Scala and Slick , Can I get some help ? , as to how to proceed implementing this feature. Is there any slick/scala pattern to do this at application level.

My problem is "I have pool of connections of different shards of MySQL, when I write a query/queries involving ID's (sharding keys), slick should dynamically run that particular query on the respective database shard"

For Example: If I write a query like this

```
  val q = for ( user <- users.filter(_.name === "cat")

                post <- posts.filter(_.postedBy === user.id)

                comment <- comments.filter(_.postId === post.id)

                } yield comment.content

    q.run

    a trivial case should be like one below.

    users += User(id = 1, name = "cat", email = "cat@mat.com") => hits shard no 1
```

Even if the User ID, Post ID, Comment ID are dynamically produced, slick should hit the correct database shard using some sharding criteria ( key (ID) % 3 ) and everything should happen at the background just like single database query.

To implement the feature at application level

Is there any way to read Query object state dynamically so that I can write a function like

```
 def func(q: Query[Something], shards: Map[Int, Database], num: Int): Unit = {

           shards(q.getId % num).withSession{ implicit session => {

              q.run

          }
 }
```

Usage:

```
     val q = users.insert(User(id = 1, name = "cat", email = "cat@cat.com"))

     func(q, shards, 10) => q executes on one of the 10 shards.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Slick is a quite advanced Scala library. Changing it's implementation will be tough when you are new to Scala. This is a very broad question. If you try it and have more specific questions on the way, changes are higher that people will answer.

Comment: is there any slick pattern to do this at application level. @cvogt

Comment: Will this be implemented in typesafe Slick in future ? how long it would take ?

Comment: This is very low priority. It may never be implemented by us. An application level pattern would probably be a function from ids to slick Database objects, that basically tells, which shard is responsible for the ids.

Comment: is there any way to read id information from a Query object, so that i can do something like this `def function(q: Query[Something], dbs: Map[Int, Database], num: Int): Unit = { dbs(q.getId % num).withSession{implicit session => q.run }}`

Comment: Why do you need to do it on application level, and not on database level?

Comment: @Ashalynd ya, Database level also works for me. but, how can we implement this feature at Database level, say am using MySQL . Thanks

Comment: I would say, talk to your DBA :) If DBA is you then you need to figure out yourself how to set up the sharding (e.g. what sharding key / number of shards would be the best for your case).

Comment: @Ashalynd . what if someone want to build something like MySQL proxy using Scala Slick for various reasons ? am just wondering if we can build that functionality transparently at application level using Actor Systems for local transparency and scaling out uniformly

Comment: I would say that Slick is too high-level for that.

Comment: correction in above comment "location transparency and scaling out uniformly"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62630/discussion-between-pamu-and-ashalynd).